# Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment ROR version 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am trying to deploy my ROR(v7) app on a VPS using Nginx and Passenger. I am getting this error from Passenger:

> Error: The application encountered the following error: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `bin/rails credentials:edit` (ArgumentError)

I have used `RAILS_ENV=production EDITOR=nano rails credentials:edit` to edit the credentials which takes me to
/tmp/91086.credentials.yml:

```
# Used as the base secret for all MessageVerifiers in Rails, including the one protecting cookies.
secret_key_base: (blah blah)
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

I don't know why it is still saying this, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the SECRET_KEY_BASE environment variable set?

Comment: How do you deploy your application? With capistrano?